# Optimization creating the factorial representation of number

Tags: java, optimization, numbers, factorial

I create the factorial representation of `x` by dividing `x` through `2,3,4,5,...` until `x` is `zero`, thus `x` is `256^50000` and greater this takes several seconds. Is there a faster way to create the factorial representation of a number than the mentioned one? I am using java.

Example:

```
public List<Integer> toFactorialRepresentation(BigInteger x){
  List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<>();
  for(BigInteger i = TWO; !x.equals(ZERO); i=i.add(ONE)){
    BigInteger[] bigg = x.divideAndRemainder(i);
    out.add(bigg[1].intValueExact());
    x=bigg[0];
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by “factorial representation?” Also, can you share the code you have right now?

Comment: added example code

Comment: to alleviate confusion...  factorial != factored.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is always dividing your number by 2 and get first factors. (Like 1000 can get 2^3 from this)
Second thing is loop divisors from 3 to square root of x, and each loop increase iterator by 2 (3, 5, 7 and so on).
*I think simple way above will help you a little bit.*